# Adaptação de Código VBA para buscar fotos de uma pasta

Tags: microsoft-excel, imagem, macro, inserir

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma macro, o qual busca numa planilha o nome da foto (ex: IMG0102.JPG), busca numa pasta predefinida a foto relacionada e a insere na célula que está o nome da foto.

Contudo, necessito atualizar essa planilha todos os dias com novas fotos, no entanto toda vez que executo a macro ele duplica todas as fotos que eu já havia inserido. Portanto, necessitaria que esse macro pulasse cada célula com foto (para não duplicar as que já tem) e seguisse somente para as células sem fotos

Segue exemplo da planilha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a macro que procura a célula com o nome da foto e procura na pasta:

```
    Sub InserirFotos()
imgpasta = "xxxxxxxxx\" ' caminho da pasta das fotos

For i = 2 To 1000 'Numero das Linhas ' inicio e fim para inserir fotos
For j = 28 To 35 'Numero das Colunas ' inicio e fim das colunas de onde estao os nomes das fotos

        imgleft = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Left
        imgtop = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Top
        imgwidth = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Width
        imgheight = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Height
        imagem = Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value)

    If imagem <> "" Then
    If Dir(imgpasta + imagem) <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture imgpasta + imagem, True, True, imgleft, imgtop, imgwidth, imgheight
    End If
    End If

Next j
Next i

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.SelectAll
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize

End Sub
```

Comment: Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/290851/75104)

Comment: Meu caro, estou meio corrido aqui e não olhei o código, mas, conforme você disse que esta funcionando, seria mais fácil você criar uma nova coluna tipo Estatus, e ao gravar a imagem esta coluna recebe um valor entre 0 e 1. Onde 0 não tem foto e 1 tem foto. Quando for analisar o código para gravar a fotos verifica o estatus primeiro para depois inserir a foto. Tente aí, caso não consigo, vou dar uma olhada no código.

Comment: Bom dia Kevin Valente, Criei o código pra você, espero que de certo. Obs.: Tentei colocar o código aqui, mas, tive alguns problemas com o código, prefere então inserir o link para download. CRIANDO E ATUALIZANDO LISTA DE IMAGENS DA PASTA DO WINDOWS. LINK PARA DOWNLOAD DO ARQUIVO: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1poR5-FSLko3-AcHKrHxQKAG9u9BYg5Bm [![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YEqc.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YEqc.jpg)

Comment: Você deve sempre colocar o código diretamente na sua resposta, porque se esse link se quebrar, no futuro, sua resposta não terá mais utilidade.

Comment: Tentei colocar, mas, a própria página da Stackoverflow confundo o que é código com comentários, mistura linhas de códigos e retira linhas de código passando a ser uma escrita na página. Por isso postei o link. Mas, se conseguir resolver este problema ou me mostrar como resolver posto o código aqui.

Comment: Depois de inserir o código no seu texto você pode selecionar todas as linhas de código e clicar no botão `{ }` (Amostra de código), ou você pode também acrescentar manualmente 4 espaços no início de cada linha de código, assim o editor já saberá que aquele trecho é de código, e fará a formatação adequada. Ou então, se não conseguir, posta de forma errada mesmo, que depois alguém edita a sua mensagem para arrumar a formatação.

Comment: Favor ler [como editar código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) e editar a sua resposta

Answer (score 0):

Todos os seus arquivos estão passando por aqui:

```
If imagem <> "" Then
    If Dir(imgpasta + imagem) <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture imgpasta + imagem, True, True, imgleft, imgtop, imgwidth, imgheight
    End If
End If
```

Sugestão rápida:

```
If imagem <> "" Then

        If Len(Dir(imgpasta + imagem, vbDirectory) & "") = 0 Then

            ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture imgpasta + imagem, True, True, imgleft, imgtop, imgwidth, imgheight

        End If

    End If
```

Comment: Boa tarde, amigo. Substitui pela sua sugestão, no entanto não puxa as fotos da pasta. Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Só para entender, é uma lista que diz quais imagens tem na pasta?

Comment: O macro insere as imagens conforme nomeação das células dentro da matriz selecionada.

Answer (score 0):

Criei o código pra você, espero que dê certo.

CRIANDO E ATUALIZANDO LISTA DE IMAGENS DA PASTA DO WINDOWS.

LINK PARA DOWNLOAD DO ARQUIVO COMPLETO: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1poR5-FSLko3-AcHKrHxQKAG9u9BYg5Bm

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```vb
'--- INSERINDO E ALTERANDO FOTOS  
'--- by jeanbraga.info@gmail.com  
'--- versão 1.0  }

Option Explicit  
Public Cod         As String  
Public UCell       As Range  
Public Nome1       As String  
Public Nome2       As String  
Public strFolder   As String  
Public strFileName As String  
Public objPic      As Picture  
Public rngCell     As Range  
Public CPasta      As String  

Sub InserirImagens()

    Set UCell = Range("E1048576").End(xlUp)

    [E2].Select
    Nome1 = ActiveCell.Value

    CPasta = [A2].Value 'Caminho das fotos  
    strFolder = CPasta '"C:\Users\Jean Braga\Desktop\EXCEL IMAGENS\" 'altere o caminho para onde estão as imagens

    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If

    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.jpg", vbNormal) 'arquivos jpg

    If Nome1 = "" Then
        PrimeiraFoto

    Else

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        strFileName = Dir
        Nome1 = ActiveCell.Value
        If Nome1 = "" Then
            Nome2 = strFileName
            strFileName = ActiveCell.Value
        End If

    Loop

    Selection.Offset(-1, -1).Select
    Cod = ActiveCell.Value
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Cod + 1
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = Nome2
    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select

    strFileName = Nome2

    If strFileName = "" Then
        MsgBox "FOTOS ATUALIZADAS"
        Selection.Offset(0, -2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
        Exit Sub

    End If

    Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
    With objPic
        .ShapeRange.Top = ActiveCell.Top
        .ShapeRange.Left = ActiveCell.Left
        .ShapeRange.Height = 12.5
        .ShapeRange.Width = 23

    End With

    strFileName = Dir

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        [D2].Select
        Set UCell = Range("D1048576").End(xlUp)
        UCell.Select
        Cod = ActiveCell.Value
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Cod + 1
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = strFileName
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select

        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .ShapeRange.Top = ActiveCell.Top
            .ShapeRange.Left = ActiveCell.Left
            .ShapeRange.Height = 12.5
            .ShapeRange.Width = 23

        End With

        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

    End If

End Sub  

Function PrimeiraFoto()  

    ActiveCell.Value = strFileName
    Selection.Offset(0, -1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "1"
    Selection.Offset(0, 2).Select

    If strFileName = "" Then
        MsgBox "FOTOS ATUALIZADAS"
        Selection.Offset(0, -2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = ""
        'Exit Sub

    End If  

    Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
    With objPic
        .ShapeRange.Top = ActiveCell.Top
        .ShapeRange.Left = ActiveCell.Left
        .ShapeRange.Height = 12.5
        .ShapeRange.Width = 23

    End With  

    strFileName = Dir  

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        [D2].Select
        Set UCell = Range("D1048576").End(xlUp)
        UCell.Select
        Cod = ActiveCell.Value
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Cod + 1
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = strFileName
        Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select  

        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .ShapeRange.Top = ActiveCell.Top
            .ShapeRange.Left = ActiveCell.Left
            .ShapeRange.Height = 12.5
            .ShapeRange.Width = 23

        End With  

        strFileName = Dir  

    Loop  
End Function
```