# Macro para buscar imagens automaticamente e jogar no excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma planilha, onde necessito incluir automaticamente imagens. Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de elaborar uma macro, em que faça junção da Referência e da cor (referência&cor) e busque numa determinada pasta a foto relacionada a esse código.

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na macro é possível que quando não tenha foto na pasta nomeada com (referência&cor ex: 60557000156) tem como ela pular e continuar inserindo fotos para as próximas?

**Macro já existente:** A macro que eu utilizo em outros materiais para buscar imagens é essa abaixo, porém ela precisa ser repetida para cada imagem que eu necessitar, anteriormente eram no máximo 20 imagens, porém agora para cada página são no mínimo 78 imagens e cada aba do excel possui no máximo 6 página o que resulta em aproximadamente 468 imagens, por isso busco uma macro mais resumida;

```
Sub Macros2()

    Call Imagem1
    Call Imagem2
    Call Imagem3
    '... 
    Call Imagem20

End Sub

Sub Imagem1()

    Range("B11").Select 'This is where picture will be inserted
    Dim picname As String
    picname = Range("A6") 'This is the picture name
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("\\storage\Img_Systextil\PROJETO LUNENDER\Fotos RPN\Inverno 2018\" & picname & ".JPG").Select  'Path to where pictures are stored
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' This resizes the picture
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    With Selection
        .Left = Range("B11").Left
        .Top = Range("B11").Top
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .ShapeRange.Height = 150#
        .ShapeRange.Width = 150#
        .ShapeRange.Rotation = 0#
    End With

    Range("A10").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub

    ErrNoPhoto:
        MsgBox "Unable to Find Photo" 'Shows message box if picture not found
        Exit Sub
        Range("B20").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Sim. É possível. Até onde você chegou com sua tentativa?

Comment: Boa tarde Diego. Não consegui desenvolver nada para essa planilha em questão, o que eu sempre fiz foi utilizar uma macro já existente em outro arquivo e adaptar para os materiais novos, pois sou bastante inexperiente nesse assunto. A macro que eu utilizo precisa ser repetida dentro da programação para cada imagem que eu utilizar (ex. se eu tiver 20 imagens terei que repetir 20x) nesse arquivo novo são mais 500 imagens, então não consigo reutilizar ela. será que você consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Posta o código que você tem hoje, essa macro aí que precisa ser repetida. Talvez a partir dela possamos ajudar. Mas como a questão está agora, [provavelmente será fechada como muito ampla](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: postei na questão.

Comment: @danieltakeshi acho que tem razão. Dei uma revisada e não é bem uma duplicata. Vou retirar o voto..

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Adicionar foto em planilha excel a partir de pasta local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151434/adicionar-foto-em-planilha-excel-a-partir-de-pasta-local)

Answer (score 1):

#### Código

Segue o código de exemplo para realizar isto. A explicação está como comentário no código.

```
Dim ref As String, codImg As String, caminho As String, caminhoImg As String
Dim corRng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cor

'Declara a planilha
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
'Célula Referência
ref = ws.Range("C19")
'Intervalo de códigos das cores
Set corRng = ws.Range("C13:C15")
'Diretório com arquivos
caminho = "C:\Excel\testes"

'Loop em cada célula da Range de cores
For Each cor In corRng
    'Código do arquivo de Imagem
    codImg = ref & cor
    'Caminho inteiro do arquivo
    caminhoImg = caminho & "\" & codImg & ".jpg"
    'Insere Imagens
    With ws.Pictures.Insert(caminhoImg)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 75
            .Height = 100
        End With
        'Insere no 2, que é a coluna B e linha que está o código de cor
        .Left = ws.Cells(cor.Row, 2).Left
        .Top = ws.Cells(cor.Row, 2).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
Next cor
```