# PEDIDO de PRODUTOS no Excel com Fotos dos Produtos, via VBA

Tags: vba

Estou desenvolvendo um PEDIDO DE PRODUTOS no Excel, via VBA. Neste pedido, além da descrição do Produto - item a item, tenho os tamanhos dos mesmos (isso já fiz); Entretanto não estou conseguindo trazer para este PEDIDO DE PRODUTOS, as fotos dos produtos em si (cada produto tem a sua foto).

Para o primeiro item do Pedido de Produto, eu já consegui fazer, mas não estou conseguindo fazer que essas rotina seja feita item a item.

A linha de código que estou usando é a seguinte:

```
fotoBDProduto = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Image Files(*.jpg), *jpg")
shtPedidos.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(fotoBDProduto)
```

Onde:

fotoBDProduto = pasta ou caminho onde estão as fotos dos produtos

Image1 - é o local onde a foto deve ficar no pedido (primeiro item)
Image2 - é o local onde a foto deve ficar no pedido (segundo item) e assim por diante (mas é aqui que não estou conseguindo fazer)

OBS: Esse código está dentro de um Formulário de Inclusão - Via VBA para o Excel.

Como proceder com o código, neste caso...?

Sendo que, para que o pedido fique completo, devem ser inseridas, pelo menos 40 fotos, no mínimo, para cada pedido. Onde cada foto, significa um item deste produto.

Comment: [**Leia isto**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-nÃo-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: Perguntas relacionadas: [Macro para buscar imagens automaticamente e jogar no excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/290261/75104) e [Adicionar foto em planilha excel a partir de pasta local](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151461/75104). Pelo que entendi é parecido com as respostas dos links.